# getting WARNING: Malformed option description '[enable=]PATTERN', should look like "opt"

Tags: qemu

I am compiling QEMU

```
./configure  --target-list=x86_64-softmmu  --enable-debug --disable-gcrypt  --disable-xen --disable-git-update --disable-snappy --disable-spice --disable-libusb --disable-usb-redir --disable-rbd --disable-plugins --disable-sdl --disable-sdl-image --enable-fdt

cd build
make
```

and getting the next error:

```
WARNING: Malformed option description '[enable=]PATTERN', should look like "opt"...
```

(see below for full error log).
and the compilation stops...
I know that I can run the configuration with the flag --disable-werror, but I want to solve it (don't want to skip warnings...). Any ideas ?

```
    Generating devel manual with a custom command
Compiling C object tests/fp/libsoftfloat.a.p/berkeley-softfloat-3_source_8086-SSE_s_propagateNaNF128UI.c.o
Generating tools manual with a custom command
Generating interop manual with a custom command
Generating specs manual with a custom command
Running Sphinx v3.3.1
Running Sphinx v3.3.1
Running Sphinx v3.3.1
Running Sphinx v3.3.1
making output directory... making output directory... done
done
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 6 source files that are out of date
updating environment: building [html]: targets for 10 source files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 19 source files that are out of date
updating environment: updating environment: [new config] [new config] 10 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
19 added, 0 changed, 0 removed. [ 10%] bitmaps                                              
6 added, 0 changed, 0 removedmics                                              
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date                     
building [html]: targets for 7 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 7 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 50%] qemu-nbd                                                                                                                                              
looking for now-outdated files... none found                                   
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
reading sources... [ 21%] clocks                                                                                                                                                

Warning, treated as error:
../docs/qemu-option-trace.rst.inc:4:Malformed option description '[enable=]PATTERN', should look like "opt", "-opt args", "--opt args", "/opt args" or "+opt args"
Makefile.ninja:2573: recipe for target 'docs/tools.stamp' failed                                                                                                                
make: *** [docs/tools.stamp] Error 2
make: *** Deleting file 'docs/tools.stamp'
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
reading sources... [ 47%] memory                                                                                                                                                
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in docs/specs.
reading sources... [100%] vhost-vdpa                                           
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
reading sources... [ 84%] tcg                                                  
donerating indices... genindex reading sources... [ 89%] tcg-icount                                           
doneing additional pages... search reading sources... [ 94%] tcg-plugins                                          
doneing static files... reading sources... [100%] testing                                              
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in docs/interop.

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] testing                                               
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
```

Comment: Context, context, context. Diagnosing build issues is very hard if all you show us is a single line. You should show at least: all the arguments you passed to the commands you ran (configure, make, etc), and the last 10 or 20 lines of the output. Also say which version of QEMU you are trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what QEMU version you're building, but the problem here is an incompatibility between Sphinx 3.2 and later and the syntax used in the documentation sources in the version of QEMU you're building. You have several options here:

- Pass configure `--disable-werror` -- this should make the warning non-fatal
- Pass configure `--disable-docs` to not build the docs at all
- Use Sphinx 3.1 instead
- Use a newer QEMU which has the fix: 5.2.0 and later should be fine
- Cherry-pick the fix from the newer releases back into the one you're building (it's upstream commit `5a4b0d411283c9`)

More generally, if you're building an older version of QEMU with a fairly new host OS/distro then it's often worth checking whether newer QEMU versions have fixed the problem. It's not uncommon for newer OS versions to reveal some minor incompatibility or error in QEMU which causes a warning or even sometimes a compilation failure. We can't go back in time and fix them in the releases that have already been made, but we do fix them upstream and the fixes go into new releases.